# How to make automatic focus of tagfield on some condition

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a tagfield in which I am loading some value and sending to the server. What I want is when reload that tagfield component again, those value should be automatically selected. 
currently They are not automatically selected, But If I am giving a focus to the tagfield then those value are coming as selected.

What is the way to give automatically focus on some condition. Not all the time.

Right now I am just displaying the data but this is not correct way to do and in IE this is not working.

Here what I am doing currently

```
if(myField.xtype == "tagfield"){
        myField.xtype.setValue(myValue);
        myField.xtype.inputEl.set({'placeholder':myValue});
    }
```

What I want is

```
if(myField.xtype == "tagfield"){
        // Automatic Focus  OR
        // Someway by which I can set the value
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you are experiencing the same as [this bug report](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?344610-Tagfield-with-createOnEnter-does-not-show-value-after-loadRecord)?

Comment: @Alexander Yes a Similar kind of. My Value is getting appear when I click on focus. So I just thinking is there anyway I can get focused once I load. Also I was using my code but placeholder is not working in IE. I checked in doc and there is something called `preFocus` to avoid use of `placeholder` But I don't sure how to make use of that. Can you please help me how to use `preFocus ` or something similar

Comment: I have checked the tagfield source code. Please try whether the config option `autoLoadOnValue:true` works for you. It works in the fiddle from the bug report.

Comment: `autoLoadOnValue:true ` will work only after the store get load. But In my case I am geeting store only after tagfield component get focused.

Comment: Nope, `autoLoadOnValue` will force the store load when the value is set. At least in 6.2.1 - which version do you use?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same version. I trying with `autoLoadOnValue` but no luck.

Comment: @Alexander ANy IE11 heck for placeholder ? That also I may use to display value

Comment: Are you using `viewcontroller` for that particular form? if yes then you can use `bind` config to bind value.

Comment: Isn't `xtype` case sensitive ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your `tagfield` config object is look like this.

```
var store =  Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore',{ 
fields: [
    'abbr',
    'state',
    'description',
    'country'
],
data: [
    [0, 'AL', 'Alabama', 'The Heart of Dixie'],
    [1, 'AK', 'Alaska', 'The Land of the Midnight Sun'],
    [2, 'AZ', 'Arizona', 'The Grand Canyon State'],
    [3, 'AR', 'Arkansas', 'The Natural State'],
    [4, 'CA', 'California', 'The Golden State'],
    [5, 'CO', 'Colorado', 'The Mountain State'],
    [6, 'CT', 'Connecticut', 'The Constitution State'],
    [7, 'DE', 'Delaware', 'The First State'],
    [8, 'DC', 'District of Columbia', "The Nation's Capital"],
    [9, 'FL', 'Florida', 'The Sunshine State'],
    [10, 'GA', 'Georgia', 'The Peach State'],
    [11, 'HI', 'Hawaii', 'The Aloha State'],
    [12, 'ID', 'Idaho', 'Famous Potatoes']
] 
});

{
        xtype: 'tagfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Select a state',
        store: store,
        reference: 'states',
        displayField: 'state',
        valueField: 'abbr',
        filterPickList: true,
        queryMode: 'local',
}
```

By this config if you select states like `Alabama,Alaska,Arizona` in tag fields then you will get value like this `['AL','AK','AZ']` because in tag field config you have set `valueField: 'abbr'`  and those value will go to server to save.

After reloading if you want to select those values then you have to give those three value as it is. like

```
if(myField.xtype == "tagfield"){//tagfield is in lower case 
         myField.setValue(['AL','AK','AZ']); // myField.setValue(myValue);
}
```

If you still want to focus same field and if you are loading tagfield's store on focus then you can use `focus` method of tag field.

```
if(myField.xtype == "tagfield"){ //tagfield is in lower case 
       myField.focus(true,true,function(){
       myField.getStore().load({
          callback: function(records, operation, success) {
              myField.setValue(['AL','AK','AZ']);//myField.setValue(myValue);                   
          }
       });
    }); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

If you have use tagfield as widget then you can use `onWidgetAttach` config on `widgetcolumn` and you can specify function on it.

Please refer [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html#cfg-onWidgetAttach).

Comment: Ok +1 for answer. But, here my `tagfield ` is a widget column and store is only loading after tagfield get focused. Well let me try second part of your answer.

Comment: Nope. I can not set store value without getting focused. So I wann auto focused.

Comment: do you have any fiddle ?

Comment: I will try to create one fidlle.